# Why doesn't Catch Print?

Tags: java, exception, try-catch, thread-sleep

```
try {
Thread.sleep(1000);
} catch(InterruptedException e) {
System.out.println("Interrupted, NOT PRINTED");
}
System.out.println ("This statement is printed");
```

in this code sleep throws an interrupted exception and yet this doesnt print the catch statements in the output.Why?

Comment: Where is the interrupt done ? I see no throwing here.

Comment: Add `Thread.currentThread().interrupt()` to the start.

Comment: the sleep method is supposed to throw an exception
its protoype is somewhat like this : static void sleep(long milliseconds) throws InterruptedException

Comment: @Mayank - The sleep method ***may*** throw an exception, ***if*** the sleeping thread is interrupted. Its not *guaranteed* to do so.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should read the full [Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#sleep%28long%29) for the sleep method (note the emphasis):

> #### sleep
>
> `public static void sleep(long millis)
>                     throws InterruptedException`
>
> Causes the currently executing thread to sleep (temporarily cease execution) for the specified number of milliseconds, subject to the precision and accuracy of system timers and schedulers. The thread does not lose ownership of any monitors.
>   **Parameters**:
>        millis - the length of time to sleep in milliseconds.
>   **Throws**:
>   InterruptedException - ***if any thread has interrupted the current thread***. The interrupted status of the current thread is cleared when this exception is thrown.

No exception will be thrown *unless* the sleeping thread is actually interrupted. Here is a version of the code that more reliably tests the behavior you are examining:

```
Thread targetThread = new Thread() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(5000);
            System.out.println("Target thread completed normally");
        } catch(final InterruptedException ie) {
            System.out.println("Target thread was interrupted");
        }
    }
};

targetThread.start();
targetThread.interrupt();
```